# How to set minimum Increment ++ and Decrement -- value (can't go bellow 1) + how to decrease or increase button added value

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am working on a web store which offers 2 pre-assigned options (buy two for XX and buy 3 for XY). I also added a normal - 0 + system whith which the customer can select a different number of products.

I wrote a little code which works fine for +- or 2,3 alone, but if i wanna decrease a number added by 2,3 buttons, it doesn't go from 3 to 2 but to 0 or -1. 
So, i want to be able to select pre-defined option 2 or 3 but i also want it to be editable by +- buttons.
Any suggestions?

```
<button class="gumb_shop2" onclick="spremembax()">2 for 10,99 €</button>
<button class="gumb_shop3" onclick="spremembay()">3 for 8,99 €</button>
<button class="plus" onclick="buttonClickUP();">+</button>
<input type="text" id="gumb2" value="0"></input>
<button class="plus" onclick="buttonClicDOWN();">-</button>
<input type="text" id="order" value="ORDER NOW"></input>
<script>
  function spremembax() {
    document.getElementById("gumb2").value = "2";
  }

  function spremembay() {
    document.getElementById("gumb2").value = "3";
  }
  var i = 0;

  function buttonClickUP() {
    i++;
    document.getElementById('gumb2').value = i;
    if (i <= 0) {
      i = 0;
      display(i);
    }
  }
  var i = 0;

  function buttonClickDOWN() {
    i--;
    document.getElementById('gumb2').value = i;
    if (i <= 0) {
      i = 0;
      display(i);
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `buttonClicDOWN` .......missing `k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mention in the comment, you have a typo in `buttonClicDOWN` .......missing `k`. You directly increment/decrement the value of the element. Please see the modified functions:

```html
<button class="gumb_shop2" onclick="spremembax()">2 for 10,99 €</button>
<button class="gumb_shop3" onclick="spremembay()">3 for 8,99 €</button>
<button class="plus" onclick="buttonClickUP();">+</button>
<input type="text" id="gumb2" value="1"></input>
<button class="plus" onclick="buttonClickDOWN();">-</button>
<input type="text" id="order" value="ORDER NOW"></input>
<script>
  function spremembax() {
    document.getElementById("gumb2").value = "2";
  }

  function spremembay() {
    document.getElementById("gumb2").value = "3";
  }

  function buttonClickUP() {
    var el = document.getElementById('gumb2');
    el.value = Number(el.value) + 1;
  }

  function buttonClickDOWN() {
    var el = document.getElementById('gumb2');
    if(el.value == 1) return false;
    el.value = Number(el.value) - 1;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works :) Another question, how can i set minimum value to 1? So it cannot go uder 1?

Comment: @Dadinho28, simple return false when value is 1......`if(el.value == 1) return false;`....updated the answer....please check

Comment: Thank you. :) Since i have 0 experience with Javascript i could never figure that out on my own :/. It took me like an hour just to create the code i posted above :/. Another question is, how can i add the value from that field to URL? For example if the customer selects 3 the url when he presses ORDER NOW is "http://example.com/3"

Regards,
David

Comment: @Dadinho28, I am not clear about the url here.....but you can change the value with `document.getElementById("order").value = "example.com/" + "3";`

Comment: We have a landing page on this site but the order will be completed on another. So i must append the value from the button to url. So for example if the user enters 3 the url should be www.example.com/quantity=3.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `input type="number"`?

```html
<button class="gumb_shop2" onclick="gumb2.value=2">2 for 10,99 €</button>
<button class="gumb_shop3" onclick="gumb2.value=3">3 for 8,99 €</button>
<input type="number" id="gumb2" value="1" step="1" min="1" />
<input type="button" id="order" value="ORDER NOW" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately i have to use + - buttons, because i recieved a mock-up i have to realize.

Comment: Maybe the author of that mockup wasn't aware that `input type="number"` exists?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have this added as a comment, but was not able to for missing rep. So an answer:

---

In simple terms: you are not updating your global variable **i** when pressing the **2** or **3** button, so when you in/decrease **i** and assign it to the value property, you do override the old value.

I would recommend to drop the *i* (global) variable and just to work with the value property, e.g.

```
function buttonClickDOWN() {
    var elm = document.getElementById('gumb2');
    if (elm.value > 0) 
        elm.value--;
    else 
        elm.value = 0;
}
```

P.S.: as you are using a **text** type input, you might also want to consider non-numbers the user might have entered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example that that meets your specs:

```
<button onclick="setAbs(event)" data-val="2">2 for 10,99 €</button>
<button onclick="setAbs(event)" data-val="3">3 for 8,99 €</button><br/><br/>
<button onclick="down()">-</button>
<input size="2" id="counter" value="0" />
<button onclick="up()">+</button><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<script>
  let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
  function setAbs(event){
    counter.value = event.target.dataset.val;
  }
  function up(){ 
    counter.value = parseInt(counter.value) + 1;
  }
  function down(){ 
    if(counter.value > 0){
      counter.value = parseInt(counter.value) - 1;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer i was looking for.

Thank you @Mamun for quick response.

```
<button class="gumb_shop2" onclick="spremembax()">2 for 10,99 €</button>
<button class="gumb_shop3" onclick="spremembay()">3 for 8,99 €</button>
<button class="plus" onclick="buttonClickUP();">+</button>
<input type="text" id="gumb2" value="1"></input>
<button class="plus" onclick="buttonClickDOWN();">-</button>
<input type="text" id="order" value="ORDER NOW"></input>
<script>
  function spremembax() {
    document.getElementById("gumb2").value = "2";
  }

  function spremembay() {
    document.getElementById("gumb2").value = "3";
  }

  function buttonClickUP() {
    var el = document.getElementById('gumb2');
    el.value = Number(el.value) + 1;
  }

  function buttonClickDOWN() {
    var el = document.getElementById('gumb2');
    if(el.value == 1) return false;
    el.value = Number(el.value) - 1;
  }

</script>
```